# How put a custom-made symbol from newcommand into the range of setmathfont?

Tags: fontspec, unicode, unicode-math, renewcommand

Following up on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/600002/179653) question, I am trying to use a unicode character as a binary operator. The answer in the linked question helped me do this, but I am running into a second issue. I want to also use a custom symbol as a binary operator:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{Symbola}[range={\sphericalangleup,\lang},Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newcommand{\ang}{\mathbin{\sphericalangleup}}
\newcommand{\lang}{\mathbin{\raisebox{1pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-116}{\sphericalangleup}}}}

This character prints: $\ang$

But this does not: $\lang$

And by the way \textbf{bold} works fine :)

Unless I use the fontspec command...
\fontspec{Symbola}

After which the character prints: $\lang$

Except now \textbf{bold} doesn't work :(
```

[image]

I tried just throwing the command `\lang` for my custom symbol into the range of `setmathfont`, but this doesn't work, as shown above. `fontspec` solves this problem but creates another (see above).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `\sphericalangleup` is a math command, you need to start math mode in the `\raisebox`.

On the other hand, it's not necessary to define a math font, which Symbola isn't.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\newfontface{\symbolafont}{Symbola}
\newcommand{\symbolasphericalangleup}{\text{\symbolafont\symbol{"29A1}}}

\newcommand{\ang}{\mathbin{\symbolasphericalangleup}}
\newcommand{\lang}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \raisebox{1pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-116}{\symbolasphericalangleup}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

This character prints: $\ang$

But this does not: $\lang$

And by the way \textbf{bold} works fine :)

\end{document}
```

[image]